# Validating radio button with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I have a form (a dynamically created questionnaire) with multiple questions. I have used jQuery to style the radios as buttons (http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/#radio) but I've cut down the code slightly here...

```
<div class="yesnoradios">
    <input type="radio" name="section<%= section %>_question<%= question %>" id="section<%= section %>_question<%= question %>_Y" value="Y" />Yes
    <input type="radio" name="section<%= section %>_question<%= question %>" id="section<%= section %>_question<%= question %>_N" value="N" />No
    <input type="radio" name="section<%= section %>_question<%= question %>" id="section<%= section %>_question<%= question %>_NA" value="NA" />N/A
</div>
```

So, I have multiple instances of the above, with dynamically named `id`'s.

I'm struggling to client-side validate the form on submit. What I need to do is ensure that one answer is selected for each question. I don't have a lot of experience of jQuery so all I've done so far is loop around each question.

```
$('.yesnoradios').each(function(index) {
    alert($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

I thought I'd mention, when viewing the page in English, it's using `select`'s instead of radio button which I'm able to validate fine, but the reason I can't use that in this instance is that the user is viewing the page in a language where the equivalent of 'Yes' or 'No' is different depending on how you structure the question, so I'm using ticks and crosses.

Thanks in advance for any help.

**Edit:** What I've tried to do is use the .children() function to check if one is checked and if not set a flag that says the form is invalid. But I cannot get the syntax right, and haven't been able to find a good code sample for this yet.

Comment: Might be too late but [this plugin](http://elclanrs.github.com/jq-idealforms/) could help.

Comment: Great looking plugin. Definitely will use that in future projects. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have a lot of the below ...

```
<div class="yesnoradios">
    <input type="radio" name="section<%= section %>_question<%= question %>" id="section<%= section %>_question<%= question %>_Y" value="Y" />Yes
    <input type="radio" name="section<%= section %>_question<%= question %>" id="section<%= section %>_question<%= question %>_N" value="N" />No
    <input type="radio" name="section<%= section %>_question<%= question %>" id="section<%= section %>_question<%= question %>_NA" value="NA" />N/A
</div>
```

you can use this to see if at least one of all the groups is selected by using the following code

```
$('.yesnoradios input[type=radio]:checked').length
```

This will give you the exact no of groups which have been checked.  Check it with the no of `class="yesnoradios"` and if you have the same no then at least one of the radios in each yesnoradio div have been checked

```
if($('.yesnoradios').length == $('.yesnoradios input[type=radio]:checked').length){
    //all groups have at least one radio checked
}else{
    //not all are chedked and you can loop your else logic here
}
```

**Note:** All your radios in one group should have same name... and since you have posted unrendered html here i'd assume that it does so.

Comment: Hi LoneWOLFs, yes they do all have the same name. Thanks for the code snippet, will give that a try.

Answer (score 3):

```
if ($('input[name='+ radioName +']:checked').length) {
           // at least one of the radio buttons was checked
           return true; // allow whatever action would normally happen to continue
      }
      else {
           // no radio button was checked
           return false; // stop whatever action would normally happen
      }
```

Comment: This won't check if all the `yesnoradio` classes are validated... he will have to do this in a loop checking all div's.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Your html should be like

```
radio buttons with class "optionCls" in a div with id question1
radio buttons with class "optionCls" in a div with id question2
.
.
```

Now you can refer it like

```
if($('#question1.optionCls :checked').length() > 0) 
     alert('valid'); //will tell you for question1 whether answer is selected or not
```

Build your logic to make it as dynamic